# Transformation of object based on axis

Tags: sculpting

ive been doing some sculpting in blender and i run into a problem that i need a proper transformation of my object. I tried with rotation but it does not help. This is what im talking about:
[image]
I want the last horn, the big one, to actualy be like the first two horns : "MIRROR-ED" , but i seem to cannot do it right. This is what Happens when i do SHIFT+D to copy object(Duplicate)
[image]
I tried rotation, and this is kinda "best" what i can get :
[image]
Which does not look right.
So, how do i get a mirror of my right side big horn to be on left?
Actualy, the first two horns had the same problem, but its not that visable, so i left it like that. But for big one i need fix. Any help?

Comment: perhaps duplicate then S Y -1?

Comment: You can delete the entire site of vertices of the horn you don't like and then add a mirror modifier.

Comment: Okay, i just tried what moonboots said and it worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes...I get it... But i didnt know you could do that thing like : S , Y , -1... that -1 was nonsense at first glance... But it works now fine. 
So i guess its answered question! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a mirrored copy of your horn, right? Select your horn, apply its rotation and scale with <kbd>ctr</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>, duplicate it with a <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> (or <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> if you want a linked duplication), then press <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>-1</kbd>, the duplication will be mirrored.